# What is difference between Cloud Firestore BETA and just Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to set up my Firebase Project but there is some issue about a region.
I live in Korea and I want to use Cloud Firestore.

So I just searched about this but the problem is here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgvUk.jpg

I can see the cloud firestore is available in US region

but the in the asia region the only firestore BETA is available
and there is no green circle with just-firestore

https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?region=asia-pacific#region

what is difference between them?(firestore BETA and just firestore) and how do I get my purpose to use firestore in Korea and service to Korean people?
Which I have to choose?

thank you for reading

Comment: :) one is FILEstore other one is FIREstore

Comment: @svkaka I`m so foolish sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you linked, you are actually talking about 2 different products:

- Cloud [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/) (actually also in Beta as of now) is a fully managed NoSQL document database.
- Cloud [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/) is a fully manage file storage service for applications that require a filesystem interface and a shared filesystem for data

Comment: I was a fool really sorry, then it means I can`t use Firestore in TOKYO
(asia-northeast1) or any Asia server right?

Comment: Right, FiRestore isn't available in Asia regions at the moment.

Comment: Keep checking though. Firestore is rolling out to many regions as we speak, so it may be coming to `asia-northeast1` data centers soon.

Comment: @LundinCast @Frank van Puffelen https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations This official site lists possible locations. Which is the opposite of the Google Cloud Platform official site I`m so confused what is correct??